# Question regarding how a public SharePoint site is made

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I had a look at http://www.westernaustralia.com/au/Pages/Welcome_to_Western_Australia.aspx and I know it's a SharePoint site and I am wondering how it could have been made.

I am mostly interrested in the center column (What's On). Is it an announcement list with thumbnails and Find out more links are pointing to wiki pages? Could it be a custom web part or is it possible to do this sort of thing with SharePoint 2010 out of the box?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the emitted HTML it looks like a custom user control in the page layout to me (hell I could be wrong)

That said though it is possible to do this OOTB and I could build that functionality using the Content Query Web Part and some custom XSL

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with a "What's New" web part. Customize your library view setting and set your webpart to use that view.  Add a simple content editor at the bottom of this web part and add those other links like View All etc...

Remember that you can create your own list and make sure to index it so that it can rollback into the What's New webpart.